# calculate "word" occurence in php

Tags: php, html

```
  $answers = array("a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a");
  $S1Q1 = $_POST['S1Q1'];
  $S1Q2 = $_POST['S1Q2'];

  $S2Q1 = $_POST['S2Q1'];
  $S2Q2 = $_POST['S2Q2'];
  $S2Q3 = $_POST['S2Q3'];
  $S2Q4 = $_POST['S2Q4'];

  $totalValue .= "About OM | Question 01: " . $S1Q1 . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . ($S1Q1 == $correct[0]) ? 'Correct' : 'Wrong' . "\n";
  $totalValue .= "        | Question 02: " . $S1Q2 . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . ($S1Q2 == $correct[1]) ? 'Correct' : 'Wrong'  . "\n\n";

    $totalValue .= "About EHS         | Question 01: " . $S2Q1 . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . ($S2Q1 == $answers[2]) ? 'Correct' : 'Wrong' . "\n";
    $totalValue .= "                   | Question 02: " . $S2Q2 . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . ($S2Q2 == $answers[3]) ? 'Correct' : 'Wrong' . "\n";
    $totalValue .= "                   | Question 03: " . $S2Q3 . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . ($S2Q2 == $answers[4]) ? 'Correct' : 'Wrong' . "\n";
    $totalValue .= "                   | Question 04: " . $S2Q4 . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . ($S2Q2 == $answers[5]) ? 'Correct' : 'Wrong' . "\n\n";
```

I have the above php script, what method or function can I use to calculate how many Correct and how many Wrong the user has in a loop and then calculate percentage?

**Example**:
Correct: 4 
Wrong: 2 
Total: 6 
Percentage Correct: ((4/6) * 100) =
66.666666666% => round it to **66%**

Comment: `$right++`, `$total++` as appropriate, then `sprintf('%0.2f', ($right / $total) * 100)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty way to accomplish it without changing what you already have:

```
$correct = substr_count($totalValue, "Correct\n");
$wrong = substr_count($totalValue, "Wrong\n");
$total = $correct + $wrong;
$percentage = floor($correct / $total * 100);
```

---

That said, I think this could be done much better. I would pass the variables in as an array. Your post string would look something like this:

```
answers[s1][q1]=a&answers[s1][q2]=b&answers[s2][q1]=c&answers[s2][q2]=a
```

This would be received by PHP like this:

```
answers => Array(
    's1' => Array(
        'q1' => 'a',
        'q2' => 'b'
    ),
    's2' => Array(
        'q1' => 'c',
        'q2' => 'a'
    )
)
```

Take a look at [this example](http://codepad.org/T15Ui0Md#output). It looks a bit longer and perhaps a bit more complicated, but it is much more flexible and expandable. If you need to add any questions, answers, etc...all you have to do is add the corresponding array entry. In the long run, I think you will be much happier with that.

Comment: i commented on your example you provided, please let me know if it's correct and again, you went the extra mile so thank you!

Comment: @ Travesty3: Please check Codepad.

Comment: @ Travesty3... i responded, please check

Comment: http://codepad.org/Nlvb7Nls  < can you check to make sure I got it all correct. I want to send myself an email with the information. Once you validate, i am good to go. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it looks correct to me. But of course, you should always test your code before putting it into production. Don't rely on my word that it is good.

Comment: One last question, because there will be alot of questions and mistakenly the user might skip one. I want to do a validation to ensure the name and department is filled in and also no question is left out. I want your script to execute once everything is filled in. How do i add a script which checks for validation in PHP? Because if i do in Javascript and it's disabled, it's pointless.

Comment: I would do something like [this](http://codepad.org/CztdN0Fo). In the file that generates your HTML (I called it questions.php in my example), check to see if `$_GET["errors"]` is empty and if not, loop through it and display the errors to the user.

Comment: Would it be possible to incorporate the following JQuery into the PHP to validate, so this way everything is in one file: http://jsfiddle.net/aVVW9/21/

Comment: You could put it all on one big PHP file if you want. Near the top of the file (before you output your HTML), check to see if the form has been submitted (give your submit button a name and a value, and check `$_POST` for that) and if so, go through the PHP code I gave you to check the answers. Produce the HTML if the form wasn't submitted (or if you want to produce it anyways...your choice). Put the jQuery in the usual spot in the HTML part. Make the form submit to itself (`action=""`). If you set it up right, the form will do the jQuery validation and then POST to the PHP code.

Comment: The fiddle i posted, how do I use the submit to first test for validation in javascript on client side before executing the php file?

Comment: Keep it exactly as you have it, except make the `action` attribute on the form submit back to itself, and change your submit button to this: `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit form" />`. Then, at the top of your PHP code, check if the form was submitted like this: `if ($_POST["submit"] == "Submit form") { /* do the PHP answer checking stuff */ }`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of distinct variables, you'll have to work with arrays. E.g. instead of this

```
$S2Q1 = $_POST['S2Q1'];
$S2Q2 = $_POST['S2Q2'];
$S2Q3 = $_POST['S2Q3'];
$S2Q4 = $_POST['S2Q4'];
```

do something like so:

```
$s2 = array();
for ($i=1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $s2[$i] = $_POST['S2Q'.$i];
}
```

and so on...
Please forgive possible syntax glitches, it's been a while since I did PHP :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, in your `$correct` array, you would have the key be the same as the name of the question (e.g. `S1Q1`, `S2Q1`...etc). This would allow you to lookup the answer for any of the questions. You can then loop through the questions and lookup the right answer for that question and keep a correct count. Something like:

```
//array of correct answers
$correct = array("S1Q1"=>"a", "S1Q2"=>"b", "S2Q1"=>"c", "S2Q2"=>"a", "S2Q3"=>"a", "S2Q4"=>"a");

$correctCount = 0;
$totalValue = '';

//loop through posted answers and check
foreach($_POST as $question=>$answer){
    //check if there is an answer for this question.
    if(array_key_exists($correct, $question)){
        $totalValue .= "Question {$question}: ".($correct[$question]==$answer?'Correct':'Wrong').'<br>';
        $correctCount += ($correct[$question]==$answer?1:0);
    }
}
$pct = round($correctCount/count($correct)*100);

$totalValue .= "You got {$correctCount} out of ".count($correct)." ({$pct}%) answers correct.";
```